# Cannot convert value of generic type to expected argument of associated type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3

Say I have a protocol:

```
protocol Foo:Hashable, Comparable {}
```

And a struct that has this guy as a generic:

```
struct UsingFoo<T:Foo> {}
```

So far so good. Say I want to use `Foo` on a second protocol:

```
protocol Bar {
    associatedtype FooType:Foo
    func doSomething(with:UsingFoo<FooType>)
}
```

And use Bar on a class:

```
class UsingBar<F:Foo>:Bar {
    typealias FooType = F
    func doSomething(with: UsingFoo<F>) {}
}
```

Now say I want to bring these guys to a party:

```
class FooBarParty<F:Foo, B:Bar>: NSObject {
    var b:B
    init(b:B) {
        self.b = b
        // interestingly, this line below won't compile
        // self.b = UsingBar<F>.init()
    }

    func thisWillCompile () {
        UsingBar<F>.init().doSomething(with: UsingFoo<F>.init())
    }

    func thisWontCompile() {
        b.doSomething(with: UsingFoo<F>.init())
    }

    func thisAlsoWont (anotherB:B) {
        anotherB.doSomething(with: UsingFoo<F>.init())
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UsingFoo<F>' to expected argument type 'UsingFoo<_>'
```

The question is: How can I ever use a property of type `Bar`? As always, any comment very appreciated

**EDIT**: Thanks to the accepted answer I figured out I should have specified `FooType`. It would look like this:

```
class FooBarParty<F:Foo, B:Bar> where B.FooType == F { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question here basically is:

> Why can't I use an instance of `B` to call `doSomething(UsingFoo<F>())`, but I can with an instance of `UsingBar<F>`

The problem lies in your associated type - `FooType`.

The `doSomething` method says that it only accepts arguments of type `UsingFoo<FooType>`. We know that in `UsingBar<F>`, `FooType` is `F`. So `UsingBar<F>().doSomething` requires a `UsingFoo<F>`. And in `thisWillCompile`, you give it a `UsingFoo<F>`! It works!

Now you get another random instance of `B` and call `doSomething`. What argument does it need? `UsingFoo<FooType>`, you might say. Well, what is `FooType` here? We don't know! It can be `F`, or `String` if we add this extension right here:

```
extension String: Foo { }
```

`FooType` can be anything that implements `Foo`. It doesn't need to be `F`. But you're passing it a `UsingFoo<F>`. That's why it does not work!

As you said, this line does not work either:

```
self.b = UsingBar<F>.init()
```

You need to be aware that `B` is *not* `Bar`. It can be any type that implements `Bar`, not necessarily `UsingBar<F>`. What you're doing is essentially:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
class C: A {}
let obj: B = C()
```

That's why that does not compile.